# GCP cloud DNS : automatic Return route for Type 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

i am referring to https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones#return-route
which says " For Type 1 targets, Google Cloud automatically adds a special return route for the 35.199.192.0/19 destination."

Topology that I am running is simple -
I am trying to use a VM (10.10.10.100) in VPC as a authoritative DNS server and internal VM1 + VM2 (10.10.10.2 and 10.10.10.3) on VPC to use this server as DNS server.
In Cloud DNS , I set forward rule saying anything for gcp.example.com ; send to 10.10.10.100.
I hope this qualifies for TYPE 1 as mentioned in given URL . But i don't see any auto injected route and hence not able to make this work . Any suggestions ?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this on serverfault ... https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Did you solve this problem? How are you listing the routes?